# Script does not work with $(document).ready(function() {}

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Im working on an ASP.NET MVC application.
Im trying to create a dialog window with jQuery UI. But, whenever I add `$(document).ready(function() {}` to my code, it doesnt work anymore.
Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#loginContainer").dialog({
        width: 340,
        height: 340,
        resizable: false,
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        }
    });

    $(".openLogin").click(function () {
        $("#loginContainer").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

And here are the bundles I've added

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                 "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.js",
                "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));


    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.core.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.resizable.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.selectable.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.accordion.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.autocomplete.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.button.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.dialog.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.slider.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.tabs.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.datepicker.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.progressbar.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/jquery.ui.theme.css"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
}
```

And in my _Layout.cshtml

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/ui-lightness/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you debugged the javascript in a browser? It seems from the question that the dialog works as expected without the doc ready function, so the javascript should then be dying on that line, usually if doc ready is failing the jQuery script hasn't been loaded correctly.

Comment: Please post the rendered CSS from the page you are trying to debug by viewing the source. I suspect that you have multiple `@Scripts.Render("jquery")` which would cause a conflict.

Comment: I posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that you have multiple @Scripts.Render("jquery"), possibly in both _Layout and Index, which would cause a load conflict.